# How to create a docker image which depends on private go packages that are hosted within a subgroup in gitlab?

Tags: git, docker, go, ssh, gitlab

I'm working on a go project which imports a private package. The private package repo is inside a subgroup in gitlab. I have my development environment set up using a `~/.netrc` file and setting `GOPRIVATE="gitlab.mycompany.io"` and everything works fine.

However, running `go mod download` during the docker build always fails.

What is *REALLY WIERD* is that if I build a container which includes all steps before `RUN go mod download` I can run the container interactively and execute `go mod download` inside the container without issue.

Here is what my `Dockerfile` looks like:

```
FROM golang:latest AS builder

# Adds .netrc
ARG NETRC
RUN echo $NETRC > ~/.netrc
ENV GOPRIVATE="gitlab.mycompany.io/*"
ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
RUN mkdir ~/.ssh && echo "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
RUN echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa && chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN go mod download && go mod verify
RUN GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -ldflags="-w -s"


# FROM scratch (...etc.)
```

I am running this with the following command, where `NETRC` and `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` contain the cat output of those files.

```
docker build --no-cache --build-arg NETRC=$NETRC --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY -t test-downloader .
```

This `Dockerfile` fails with:

```
remote: 
        remote: ========================================================================
        remote: 
        remote: The project you were looking for could not be found.
        remote: 
        remote: ========================================================================
        remote: 
        fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

        Please make sure you have the correct access rights
        and the repository exists.
```

Can anyone help me understand:

1. Is there a difference between environments when docker runs a command as a build step and when I run a container interactively?
2. How to make this work? :)

**Additional info:**

1. The .netrc, .gitconfig, and ssh key look as they should inside the container.
2. I have tried authenticating with `.git-credentials` and git url (using `insteadOf` in git config). This fails with the same error and also fails when I run `go mod download` inside a container that has all preceding steps.
3. I have tried using all manner of replace directives in the `go.mod` file in order to point mod to the correct package, one such attempt was:

```
    ...
    gopkg.in/yaml.v2 v2.2.7
)

replace gitlab.mycompany.io/maingroup/subgroup/myapp v0.0.0 => gitlab.mycompany.io/maingroup/subgroup/myapp.git v0.0.0
```

Comment: You wrote that you can execute `go mod download` interactively. This makes me wonder what is default user in your docker build script and what user are you connecting interctively to docker image as?

Comment: The default user is root and I am also root when running the image interactively.

Answer (score 1):

### Alternative solution that worked for me

Perhaps not the answer you are looking for, but a way that worked for me would be to not try to do any sort of authentication or credential stuff in your Dockerfile and go with vendoring the apps. I personally dislike having to have a vendor folder but this is better than having to deal with authentication in Docker.

You would run `go mod tidy` and `go mod vendor` outside the Docker command, commit that and then your Dockerfile would something like this (path and workdir might not be the correct ones, the relevant part is how to build):

```
FROM golang:1.13-alpine AS build-stage

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app
RUN go build -mod=vendor

# Final Stage
FROM alpine

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy only the binary so that your Docker image does not have the uncompiled code.
COPY --from=build-stage  /app/APP_NAME .

EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT ./APP_NAME
```

#### Cleaner solution that I haven't tried

Another solution is to figure out how to GOPROXY. I haven't tried that solution but it would be a cleaner way. You could use something like Athens: https://docs.gomods.io/configuration/authentication/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I've been able to get it working in CI by caching the vendor folder between stages.